# What's the standard practice to upgrade a sqlite database from .NET code in an installer

Tags: c#, sqlite, wix

I have a .NET application that uses a sqlite database. In the latest release we need to upgrade the schema. I am wondering what is the standard practice to upgrade a sqlite database from .NET code in an installer? We use Wix with custom actions implemented in a .NET assembly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools such as WiX and InstallShield only have native support for SQL ( WiX, InstallShield ), Oracle ( InstallShield ) and MySQL ( InstallShield - Requires MySQL Connect ).   There is nothing native in MSI and no other off the shelf solutions for installers that I'm aware of.

You can certainly roll your own ( hopefully data driven ) custom actions for dealing with this but if it was me I'd consider implementing your database servicing in your application layer.    This way your application is more fault tolerant and self servicing without needing the help of an installer.

For example if a customer was to upgrade your installer then restore an older version of your database, your application would be able to self upgrade it to the new schema.

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be creating a diff sql script - *one updating existing schema by adding, updating or removing parts that may be changed* - and execute it against outdated database.

That should be enough, since it'll change original schema with the new one.

By the way, what about the data? If database schema has changed, maybe you'll need to migrate previous database date.

If I'm not wrong, you want to do that from code, and this allows you to create a backup of the outdated database. After creating such backup, you should perform a post-schema-update action in order to migrate data, and finally you can (or not) remove the backup.